# SSIS 2008, from query to excel

Tags: ssis

Hi Im using SSIS for SQL server 2008.

I have a sql query:

```
select name, age, lastname
from table1
```

and i want the ssis to pass it to an excel file(xls).

How can I do this?

Thanks.

Comment: See if you can talk them to accepting a .csv file as the SSIS has far fewer problems creating a .CSV file. We let our clients know that exporting to Excel will cost twice what creating a .csv file and they usually decide it isn't worth it. SSIS and Excel do not play nice!

Comment: Thanks for the advice but they want xls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example of inserting data in Excel -

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertutorial/211/sql-server-integration-services-ssis-data-flow/

Comment: Thank you all for the replies!

Answer (score 1):

You will need to create a template sheet to put the data into. Once you have the template worksheet you will need to define an 'excel connection' inside your job.

once you have the excel connection you can write to the file in a `dataflow`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139836(v=sql.105).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms137643(v=sql.105).aspx

Those are some MSDN resources that talk about Excel connections and Destinations.